# Pytorch/CUDA - Cannot find GPU

Tags: ubuntu, anaconda, nvidia, pytorch

I'm trying to use my GPU to train a network. I installed PyTorch and CUDA with anaconda. I have an NVIDA GTX 860M on my computer I would like to use.

When using the command :

```
$ lspci | grep NVIDIA
```

I get the output :

```
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107M [GeForce GTX 860M] (rev a2)
```

So the graphic card is there. But in a Jupyter notebook, the following lines :

```
print(torch.cuda.device_count())
print(torch.cuda.is_available())
print(torch.version.cuda)
```

Return :

```
0
False
9.0.176
```

I have tried updating the latest Cuda driver using conda it did not solve the issue. My PyTorch version is 0.4.1.post2. I couldn't find an answer browsing through the different online forums. 
I am on Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS.
Thanks' in advance !

Comment: Have you tried using a newer version of PyTorch? Maybe it is because your Pytorch cannot match the CUDA version. Or it is possible that your CUDA version cannot match the GPU driver version. You can see the driver version with command `nvidia-smi`.